# How to get last child in a div parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the last child in of a parent div.

Actually, I'm using this:

```
var els = '#first,#second,#third';

$(els).each(function () {

  $(this).children().last().addClass('memo');

});
```

It works great for divs with only 1 child, but when the last div is inside a div inside another div, it doesn't work.

```js
var els = '#first,#second,#third';

$(els).each(function() {
  $(this).children().last().addClass('memo');
});
```

```css
.memo {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">First text
  <div>a</div>
</div>

<div id="second">Second text
  <img>b
</div>

<div id="third">Third text
  <div>Nested 1
    <div>Nested 2
      <img>c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I refer to the latest child?

Comment: Please write "here" in the child you mean. Last child is not a nested child. I updated your snippet to show what you are currently getting

Comment: Last child usually means the last child of siblings at the same level. Not the deepest one.

Comment: I think with last child you mean `img` or `parent of img` but in here they aren't children for `#third` they are descendants

Comment: Do you want the last element under each of `#first`, `#second`, `#third`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children are different from grandchildren/descendants.  [`$.children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) only looks at immediate children.

For the behavior you want, you could find all descendants using `*` and use `last()` in this scenario, if you are looking for the last descendant in each of `#first`,`#second`,`#third`

It's also important to mention that this gets the last element child, not the last text node. `jQuery` is not able to deal with text nodes directly. Credits to [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder). See [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

```js
$('#first,#second,#third').each(function () {
  $(this).find('*').last().addClass('memo');
});
```

```css
img.memo {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 5 px;
}

div.memo {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 5 px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <div>a</div>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <img>b
</div>

<div id="third">
  <div>
    <div>
    <img>c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You need remove the .last()

```js
$(els).each(function() {
  $(this).children().addClass('memo');
});
```